# Poor performance with ODP.net parameter array inserts when record contains BLOBs

Tags: oracle, blob, odp.net

I use ODP.net parameter arrays to achieve batch insert of records. This way performs very well when the records don't contain BLOB column - typically about 10,000 records can be inserted in one second.

If a record contains BLOB column, it has a poor performance - about 1,000 records need 8 ssconds.

Is there any method to batch insert records with BLOB column efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find I use odp to insert record with blob column uncorrectly.

when insert record with blob column, I use byte array to store the blob value. this way will have a poor performance.
I replace another way, use OracleBlob type to store the blob value. 
In this way, batch insert records will have a high performance.

Comment: You have the same results when reading a Blob column or only when inserting? Comparing inserting as byte array vs OracleBlob